# Find item in array and set as first index

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have the following array of persons:

```
const array = [{name: 'Glenn'}, {name: 'Rob'}, {name: 'Ronald'}]
```

And I want to find a certain person in this array, and put it as the first index in the array if it exist, like so:

```
// Rob is now first index
const array = [{name: 'Rob'}, {name: 'Glenn'}, {name: 'Ronald'}]
```

How can I achieve this? I can think of all kind of things, like using a `find` method and save the record if it exists and then removing it from the array and use the `unshift` method to set it as first index but this sounds kinda complex to me.

Preferably a ES6+ solution, and if the item doesn't exist I want to do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the array.

This approach moves all objects with the wanted name to top.

```js
const
    array = [{ name: 'Glenn' }, { name: 'Rob' }, { name: 'Ronald' }],
    first = 'Rob';

array.sort((a, b) => (b.name === first) - (a.name === first));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming sorting is too expensive to do here since it'll be slow for large arrays. There are two `O(n)` approaches you can take.

You can use a combination of `.splice` and `findIndex` if you want to mutate the original array or `.filter` with `.concat` for a non-mutating solution.

I'll show the mutating alternative since it's more effective in large arrays. Note you can always `.slice` to make it non-mutative and (shallow) clone the array:

```js
const array = [{name: 'Glenn'}, {name: 'Rob'}, {name: 'Ronald'}];
// find the first index matching a predicate
const robIndex = array.findIndex(x => x.name === 'Rob');
if (robIndex) {
  const [ rob ] = array.splice(robIndex, 1); // delete Rob
  array.unshift(rob); // add at first index
}
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with something like this:

```js
const array = [{name: 'Glenn'}, {name: 'Rob'}, {name: 'Ronald'}]
  console.log(array.sort((f,s) => f.name == "Rob" ? -1 : 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple loop is just as viable:

```js
let array = [{name: 'Glenn'}, {name: 'Rob'}, {name: 'Ronald'}];

function findAndReplace(arr, name2Shift) {
  const workingCopy = [...arr];
  // note: if you don't mind changing the original arr
  // ditch newArr, modify arr and return that
  const newArr = [...arr];
  
  workingCopy.forEach((el, i) => {
    if (el.name === name2Shift) {
      newArr.unshift(newArr.splice(i, 1).shift());
    }
  });
  
  return newArr;
}
// modified
console.log(JSON.stringify(findAndReplace(array, "Rob")));
// no modification
console.log(JSON.stringify(findAndReplace(array, "Pete")));
```

But a oneliner is also possible (using `findIndex` here)

```js
let array = [{name: 'Glenn'}, {name: 'Rob'}, {name: 'Ronald'}];
let robComesFirst = array
  .splice(array.findIndex(v => v.name === "Rob"), 1)
  .concat(array);
console.log(JSON.stringify(robComesFirst));
```